# How to compose functions without parenthesis in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out how many digits the 500th Fibonacci number is:

```
fib n = fibs (0,1) !! n where 
    fibs (a,b) = a:fibs(b,(a+b))
length (show (fib 500))
```

This does work. Is there a way to get rid of the parenthesis in the third line? Say
`length . show . fib 500` or something alike?

This dollar-form works too:

```
length $ show $ fib 500
```

Generally, what is the recommended way in this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Typical style:

```
length . show $ fib 500
```

Only compositions:

```
length . show . fib $ 500
```

One advantage to preferring composition is that you can easily pull out common subfunctions. Maybe you need `length . show` somewhere else, so you can trivially move it elsewhere and give it a name; `show . fib` is probably less useful, though. :)

What you said with:

```
length . show . fib 500
```

Is the same as:

```
\x -> length (show (fib 500)) x
```

Which the compiler sees as nonsensical because you’re using `Int` like a function.

Comment: Or, function application has higher precedence than any other infix operator, so `length . show . fib 500` is equivalent to `length . show . (fib 500)`.

Answer (score 5):

You almost got it:

```
length . show . fib $ 500
```

You can define a function in [pointless style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) for this

```
lengthOfFib = length . show . fib
```

then use it like this

```
lengthOfFib 500
```

Answer (score 3):

I would normally use dots to compose all of the functions except the last one. For example:

```
length . show $ fib 500
this . that . theOther . length . show $ fib 500
```

You could also write it as:

```
(length . show . fib) 500
(this . that . theOther . length . show . fib) 500
```

Comment: "I would normally use dots to compose all of the functions except the last one. " Thank you for this practical advice.  (length . show . fib) 500 This also makes the code clear.